# Importing Eclipse Library in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have the most basics of question : how do you import Eclipse specific library like org.polarsys.capella.core, org.eclipse.core.commands, and so on in IntelliJ IDEA ?

It seemed reading documentations that importing an Eclipse was possible/quite simple, but when doing so, all my Eclipse's specific imports are not found by IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Using libraries/plugins written for Eclipse can range from trivial to near-impossible, depending on how much of the Eclipse specific features/APIs they depend on. Fundamentally Eclipse plugins are OSGi bundles that should (at least in theory) be able to be loaded out side of "Eclipse", but many of them depend on core Eclipse bundles that makes it practically unviable to use them outside of the Eclipse ecosystem.

Comment: Right ok, thanks for your answer. And me that thought it was easy !